# How do I force users to use a network proxy in gnome (CentOS 7)?

Tags: proxy, centos7

/etc/environment does not work for new users. My dconf lock file contains:

```
/org/gnome/system/proxy/mode
/org/gnome/system/proxy/http/host
/org/gnome/system/proxy/http/port
/org/gnome/system/proxy/http/enabled
/org/gnome/system/proxy/https/host
/org/gnome/system/proxy/https/port
```

Users can still disable the network proxy via the settings menu at will. We are using privoxy as a content filter and we need to prevent users from bypassing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall off external access, so that attempts to access things that must be retrieved via the proxy can *only* be accessed via the proxy.